# Sphinx delta index ignoring main index

Tags: php, sphinx

I have a really strange problem where for some reason my indexes simply do not function as they should.

I have built a fully working delta index in Sphinx with full cron jobs to keep it all in shape and everything is fine.

Then I come to query in PHP with:

```
class sphinx_searcher{

function __construct(){

    $config = array('host'=>'localhost', 'port'=>9312);

    $this->sphinx = new SphinxClient();
    $this->sphinx->SetServer ( $config['host'], $config['port'] );
    $this->sphinx->SetConnectTimeout ( 1 );
}

function query(){

    $this->sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
    $this->sphinx->SetLimits(0, 20); // Testing first page
    $this->sphinx->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25);
    $this->sphinx->SetArrayResult ( true );
    $res = $this->sphinx->Query("040*", "media media_delta");

    if($res)
        return $res;
    else
        return $this->sphinx->GetLastError();

}
}
```

For some reason it takes one or the other index (so far only the latter).

When I query by media alone I get doc id 1 and 2 but when I query by both I get only doc id 3 which is in the delta index.

Here is my data source config:

```
source media
{
type            = mysql
sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8
sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 1, MAX(id) FROM documents
sql_query = \
    SELECT id, deleted, _id, uid, listing, title, description, tags, author_name, playlist, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_uploaded) AS date_uploaded \
    FROM documents \
    WHERE id<=( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )

sql_field_string = tags
sql_field_string = description
sql_field_string = author_name
sql_field_string = title
sql_attr_uint = deleted
sql_attr_string = _id
sql_attr_string = uid
sql_attr_string = listing
sql_attr_uint = playlist
sql_attr_timestamp = date_uploaded
sql_ranged_throttle = 0
sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM media WHERE id=$id
sql_query_killlist = SELECT id FROM documents WHERE deleted = 0

}


source media_delta : media
{
sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
sql_query = \
    SELECT id, deleted,  _id, uid, listing, title, description, tags, author_name, playlist, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_uploaded) AS date_uploaded \
    FROM documents \
    WHERE id>( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
}
```

Here is my index config:

```
index media
{
source          = media
path            = /home/sam/sphinx/var/data/media
docinfo         = extern
mlock           = 0
morphology      = stem_en, stem_ru, soundex
min_word_len        = 1
charset_type        = sbcs
min_infix_len       = 2
infix_fields        = title, tags 
enable_star     = 1
expand_keywords     = 1
html_strip      = 0
index_exact_words   = 1
}

index media_delta : media
{
source = media_delta
path = /home/sam/sphinx/var/data/media_delta
}
```

I am really confused as to what I have got wrong and am hoping some one here could help me find out what is wrong?

EDIT:

Out of using all Indexes:

```
array(9) { ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["warning"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> int(0) ["fields"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "title" [1]=> string(11) "description" [2]=> string(4) "tags" [3]=> string(11) "author_name" } ["attrs"]=> array(10) { ["deleted"]=> int(1) ["_id"]=> int(7) ["uid"]=> int(7) ["listing"]=> int(7) ["title"]=> int(7) ["description"]=> int(7) ["tags"]=> int(7) ["author_name"]=> int(7) ["playlist"]=> int(1) ["date_uploaded"]=> int(2) } ["total"]=> string(1) "0" ["total_found"]=> string(1) "0" ["time"]=> string(5) "0.000" ["words"]=> array(1) { ["040*"]=> array(2) { ["docs"]=> string(1) "2" ["hits"]=> string(1) "2" } } }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe `$res = $this->sphinx->Query("040*", "media media_delta");`? Wrong name of the delta index.

Comment: Well I mean in my config it is "media_delta" and also when I index media_delta it works perfectly fine without coming back with an error, also if sphinx could not find the index it does bail out so it seems to recognise I put two indexes in just not that I wanna query by two.

Comment: Ah @atma I see what you mean I mis spelled my second param, lol its cos I shortened the code so added the second one there myself, dumb me :P

Comment: Anyway, the problem in other thing. What you get when querying all indexes, e.g. `$this->sphinx->Query("040*");`?

Comment: I've attached the output from the Query() function :), it does say it hits on two documents but does not return the matches

Comment: Try to search with `->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN)`. In this matchmode no weighting is performed and every match weight is set to 1. So theoretically you'll get all hits. See the [weighting](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#weighting)

Comment: nope :( still nothing, grr this is starting to annoy me :(

Comment: Ok it has to be my index somehow cos I downloaded the previous versio of sphinx and I get the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working though a few possiblities, spotted the issue,

```
sql_query_killlist = SELECT id FROM documents WHERE deleted = 0
```

That says any document with "deleted=0" will disappear. I.e. will be "killed".

I suppose in this context its confusing the 'hit' is still counted in the "words" array. Despite been later killed. (the words array is the raw number before any filtering - its direct from the index - so any setFilter (or in this case the kill-list) will make it an overestimate)

So change it to

```
WHERE deleted = 1
```

:)

Always the most unexpected of things!